Is it possible to get file statistics from StorageAccessFramework?
Using Expo Filesystem i can get File Information of the Sandbox Directories using
import * as FileSystem from "expo-filesystem"

const EFS = new FileSystem() 

try {
await EFS.getInfoAsync()
} 


But is anything like this possible with files used on SAF natively?
